# NSArray giving me weird warning when in tableView function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

Im using this constant to convert rgb to a UIColor

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

As i use this within my

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

like so

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(colours[indexPath.row]);`
```

And **colours** is defines as :

```
colours = [[NSArray alloc]
           initWithObjects: @[@0x808000,@0x008080,@0x9999FF,@0x008080,@0x993366,@0xFFFF99,@0xFF8080,@0x0066CC,@0x008080,@0xFF99CC,@0x3366FF,@0x99CC00,@0x969696,@0xFF9900,@0x993300] , nil ];
```

i get an error *Invalid operands to binary expression ('id' and int)*
and a warning  *bitsmasking for introspection of Objective-C object pointers is Strongly discouraged*

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution in this way:

1. First Intitalize array of color code in the following way:

   ```
   colors = [[NSArray alloc]
          initWithObjects: @"0x808000",@"0x008080",@"0x9999FF",@"0x008080",@"0x993366",@"0xFFFF99",@"0xFF8080",@"0x0066CC",@"0x008080",@"0xFF99CC",@"0x3366FF",@"0x99CC00",@"0x969696",@"0xFF9900",@"0x993300", nil ];
   ```
2. Second in the UITableView's CellForRowAtIndexPath method. write the following code:

   ```
   NSString *colorCode = [colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   // Convert Color to RGB
   NSScanner *scanner2 = [NSScanner scannerWithString:colorCode];
   unsigned baseColor1;
   [scanner2 scanHexInt:&baseColor1];
   CGFloat listviewred   = ((baseColor1 & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0f;
   CGFloat listviewgreen = ((baseColor1 & 0x00FF00) >>  8) / 255.0f;
   CGFloat listviewblue  =  (baseColor1 & 0x0000FF) / 255.0f;
   ```
3. Give ColorCode  to cell text color like below method:

   ```
   Cell.textLable.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:listviewred green:listviewgreen blue:listviewblue alpha:1.0];
   ```

please check and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Your `colours` array contains `NSNumber` objects, so you have to convert these
to plain integers as expected by `UIColorFromRGB()`:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB([colours[indexPath.row] intValue]);
```

(Note that `NSArray` and other collection classes can only store Objective-C objects, and
`@0x808000` is a shortcut for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0x808000]`.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in the integer value of the object at index:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB([colours[indexPath.row] intValue]);
```